# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating LogonControllor servlet class

Tags: servlets

Consider In index.jsp I have a form.
When i click on submit It should call a servlet present in src.main.java directory.
The web-inf folder is present inside src.webapp folder.
Eventhough in web.xml the servlet class entry is present. 
the controllor not getting instantiated.

I have tried putting web-app outside src directory.
check in target folder, my controllor is present.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please modify question accordingly to [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check under src tab of java build path.

You have add folder up to directory src/main/java.

That is your web-app and web-inf should not present in target folder.

Now it is able to instantiate your controllor.

Comment: You know that you'll not receive any repos for answering your own question right ?

Comment: I stucked with this for long time. Since I found solution by myself.I thought of sharing to others.Then only they wont suffer a lot @onkarMusale